# Cannot assign code reviewer in Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfs-workitem

Recently we migrated to Team foundation server 2017 but our solution is still in VS 2012. Sometimes when we try to assign code review under My Work, no users are showing and Area path of the code review is also blank. After we close the Visual studio and open again, it works fine as we can able to see the work item mapped to correct area path and it allow us to select the reviewer (any user).  Is it bug or known issue ? Any work around  ?